# What is different between "used to do <something>" and "used for doing <something>"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-choice

For example, I can say "used for storing fat", or "used to store fat".  What is the difference between the two phrases?

Comment: *store fat* what's that? :O

Comment: A tissue of human body can store fat.

Comment: True..but context was important. It's better to mention that or else you may not get a proper answer or others may simply put this question 'close'. Just a good practice to follow as I see here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two sentences:

> The lizard's tail is used to store fat.
>
> The lizard's tail is used for storing fat.

mean exactly the same thing. The **s** in **used** is pronounced soft, like a **z**. In IPA, that's /juzd/.

### An auxiliary verb

**Used to** can also work as an auxiliary verb indicating the "[imperfective aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfective_aspect#English)" or "past tense with [habitual aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_aspect#Habituality_in_English)", like this:

> The lizard used to store fat in its tail, before the mad scientist altered its metabolism.

or more realistically:

> Mom used to bake cakes all the time, before she gave up eating sugar.
>
> Your jokes used to be funny.

Many people pronounce the **s** hard (unvoiced) in this sense of **used to**, resulting in this pronunciation: /just tu/ or even /jus tu/. **Used for** cannot be used in this sense.

### A synonym for *accustomed to*

**Used to** also can mean the same as "accustomed to", as in these sentences:

> My mom's cakes taste terrible at first, but you'll get used to them.
>
> The lizard is used to living in a cage.

Many people also pronounce this sense of **used to** /just tu/ or /jus tu/. **Used for** does not have this sense, either.

Comment: So they are basically the same, except for the last two uses.

Comment: Also be mindful of `The lizard's tail is a vestigial organ.  It used to store fat.`  In this case, `used to` modifies `store,` and indicates that the fat-storing function of the tail has ceased.

Comment: @Adam Indeed that's more plausible than my mad-scientist example.

Comment: How about `The lizard used to store fat it its tail, before Monsanto modified its DNA to store fat in saffron flavored lumps on its back.  Paella on the cheap!`

Comment: The last "used" there is an adjective - not to be confused with the verb, or compared to it - (it is famous for causing problems for students). Nice pron points